# preferred way of dependency bootstrapping

Tags: .net-core, inversion-of-control, mqtt, dryioc

So, here's the list of things that I'm trying to use together.

- Aspnetcore 2.0 web app
- DryIoC
- MqttServerNet

`Startup.cs`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //cut
   return IoCBootstrapper.Init(services);
}
```

IocBootsrapper

```
public static IServiceProvider Init(IServiceCollection services)
{
                var container = new Container();  
                container.WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(services,
                    throwIfUnresolved: type => type.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                    .ConfigureServiceProvider<IoCCompositionRoot>();          

                return container;

}
```

Ok, so pretty simple setup and this `IoCCompositionRoot` is just `IRegistrator` registrations of services that I use throughout the app.

Now the issue begins when I try to configure MqttServer to my app.

In `ConfigureServices` method I'm just supposed to register my server like this.

```
var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptions();
services.AddHostedMqttServer(mqttServerOptions);
```

This vanilla setup works just fine, but... Here's the thing that I need.

```
var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptions();
mqttServerOptions.SubscriptionInterceptor = context =>
{
      //instance of IUserService
      //check if user is allowed to subscribe
};
services.AddHostedMqttServer(mqttServerOptions);
```

Now the problem becomes obvious. `AddHostedMqttServer` is an extension method on `IServiceCollection` that I'm passing to my `IoCBootstrapper` to create new `Container` and do the `WithDependencyInjectionAdapter()` so it can register the DryIoC implementation of `IServiceProvider` etc., meaning I won't be able to get this instance of `IUserService` to configure my `MqttServerOptions` because they haven't yet been configured.

I'm obviously taking a wrong approach.

I did come up with a *hacky* way of doing this, but there must be a better option for this.

Any suggestions?